Why does FDisk's Editor Close when Running the Command 'a'?
I hope this message finds you well. 
I am writing because I ran the following in my OpenBSD device
and am uncertain why it stops running:
virtual-server# fdisk -e sd1 
Enter 'help' for information
sd1: 1> a
virtual-server# 

I thought a was the shortcut for add but perhaps I am mistaken. Did this command do anything? Or perhaps it crashed?

According to the man page,
the only command that begins with ‘a’ is “abort”.

It is likely that they thought they were using the related utility disklabel or confused the two some other way.
